# What does it mean by calling articles "particles"?

Tags: grammar, articles

Copi's Introduction to Logic says:

> The grammatical particles "a" and "an" may also serve to indicate quantity, but
> whether they are being used to mean "all" or "some" depends largely on the con-
> text. Thus "A bat is a mammal" and "An elephant is a pachyderm" are reasonably
> interpreted as meaning "All bats are mammals" and "All elephants are pachyderms."
> But "A bat flew in the window" and "An elephant escaped" quite clearly do not refer
> to all bats or all elephants; they are properly reduced to "Some bats are creatures
> that flew in the window" and "Some elephants are creatures that escaped."

> The particle "the" may be used to refer either to a particular individual or to all
> the members of a class. There is little danger of ambiguity here, for such a statement
> as "The whale is a mammal" translates in almost any context into the  A  proposition
> "All whales are mammals," whereas the singular proposition "The first president
> was a military hero" is already in standard form as an  A  proposition (a singular
> proposition having existential import), as discussed in the first subparagraph of this
> section.

Are "a", "an" and "the" called articles according to English grammar?

What does it mean by calling them "particles"?

Thanks.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle) says "n modern grammar, a particle is a function word that must be associated with another word or phrase to impart meaning, i.e., it does not have its own lexical definition. According to this definition, particles are a separate part of speech and are *distinct from other classes of function words, such as articles, prepositions, conjunctions and adverbs*, what is inconsistent with Copi's quote.

Comment: Particle here is a single word (unrelated to article) solely dependent on another for context, content, meaning.

Comment: Ah! Grammaticians treat particles as *waves*, i.e., indeterminate without context. Even Werner Heisenberg would have been uncertain about that.